# How to calculate percentage change using factorial analysis?

Tags: r, matlab, factorial, anova, minitab

To assess the contribution of various input factors (x, y, z) and their interactions to the response variable (A), I calculated the percentage of variance using factorial analysis in Minitab. Now I want to calculate the percentage change in A.

Say for example A is increasing when x and y are increasing and A is decreasing when z is decreasing. So how much percentage is changing in A?
Is there any other software by which I can do this analysis?

Please help me in this regards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a simple regression would provide you what you are looking for. Since you are asking how to perform this computation for both `R` and `Matlab`, I'll provide you a Matlab solution since I can use it much better.

Before proceeding with a numerical example, let's review [a little bit of theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression):

> A fitted linear regression model can be used to identify the
>   relationship between a single predictor variable xj and the response
>   variable y when all the other predictor variables in the model are
>   "held fixed". Specifically, the interpretation of βj is the expected
>   change in y for a one-unit change in xj when the other covariates are
>   held fixed—that is, the expected value of the partial derivative of y
>   with respect to xj.

Basically, this tells us that a one unit change in `xj` generates a `βj` unit change in `y`. In order to obtain percent changes, the response variable `y` must be converted to a logarithmic scale (`ln(y)`).

Now, let's see how to perform a linear regression using the [regress function](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) in Matlab. This is as simple as:

```
% Response Variable
A = rand(100,1);

% Predictors
X = randi(10,100,1);
Y = rand(100,1);
Z = randi(3,100,1);

% Beta Coefficients
b = regress(A,[X Y Z]);
```

Now, in order to retrieve percent changes instead of unit changes, the above code must be rewritten as follows (basically, a natural log is applied to `A` and percent changes are calculated multiplying the beta coefficients `b` by `100`):

```
% Response Variable
A = rand(100,1);
A = log(A);

% Predictors
X = randi(10,100,1);
Y = rand(100,1);
Z = randi(3,100,1);

% Beta Coefficients
b = regress(A,[X Y Z]);

% Percent Changes
pc = b .* 100;
```

Using arbitrary vales, let's suppose that the returned betas are:

```
b =

    0.25
   -0.06
    1.33
```

This means that: a one unit change in `X` generates a `+25%` change in `A`, a one unit change in `Y` generates a `-6%` change in `A` and a one unit change in `Z` generates a `+133%` change in `A`. The interpretation of percent changes varies following the type of the predictor variables, and you must be careful about this. Given the response variable `Y` and the predictor variable `K`:

- If `K` is a continuous variable, then `Bk = ∂ln(Y) / ∂K`, hence a one unit change in `K` generates a `100 * Bk` percent change in `Y`.
- If `K` is the natural log of a continuous variable, then `Bk = ∂ln(Y) / ∂ln(K)`, hence a `100%` change in `K` generates a `100 * Bk` percent change in `Y`.
- If `K` is a dummy variable (only two possible values: `1 = true` and `0 = false`), then the shift of `K` from `0` to `1` produced a `100 * Bk` percent change in `Y`.

Comment: Hi Tommaso, Thank you for your kind response. I have modified my questions. Please see. Hope this time I am able to explain my question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the prior question.